# Pass multiple function handles in function output

Tags: matlab

I have an m-file function and I want to use this file to to pass 2 function handles and 6 floating point numbers to the main file.  I am trying to include all 8 into an array and output that from the m-file function, but this doesn't work.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create arrays of function handles or of doubles, but in order to create an array that can contain both function handles and doubles, you need to use a [cell array](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/06/21/cell-arrays-and-their-contents/).

```
function output = myFunction(someInput)

%# create handle1, handle2, numbers 1-6
%# ...

%# assemble output:
%# output{1} contains the first handle
%# output{3} contains the first number
%# output{6} contains an array of numbers 4 through 6
output = {handle1, handle2, number1, number2, number3, [number4, number5, number6]};
```

Comment: Arrays of function handles are not recommended because of the ambiguity between indexing and invocation - in fact, recent versions of MATLAB don't even let you concatenate function handles into an array, as per http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html